# Issue while calling function in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using below directive(only the related codes added) where it sets an object in a common service property and load another partial view. From the second page controller, previously set object need to be retrieved and showed in the UI. Issue is, data not get showed in the UI even the `console.log()` gives the expected values. Is this related to an order of execution?

Directive :

```
movieBank.directive('movieSummary', function(commonServices){
    return{
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<input type="button" value="Detail" class="btn btn-primary button" ng-click="go();">',
         scope : {
             movie : '@'
         },
         link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
           scope.go = function(){
               console.log('clicked ' +scope.movie); // gives correct values
               commonServices.setMovie(scope.movie);
               commonServices.changeLocation('/movieDetail');
           };             
         }
    }
});
```

Second page conotroller:

```
movieBank.controller('movieDetailController', function($scope, commonServices){
    $scope.movie = commonServices.getMovie();
    console.log('got ' + $scope.movie);   // gives correct values
});
```

Service :

```
movieBank.service('commonServices', function(){
   var movies = [];
   var movie = {};
   return {
        getMovie : function () {
            return movie;
        },
        setMovie : function(m){
            movie = m;
       }
   };
});
```

Page :

```
<header class="panel-heading">
    <span class="title">{{movie.Title}}</span>
    <div star-rating rating-value="movie.Rating"></div>
</header>
<p class="panel-body">
    {{movie.Description}}
</p>
<div class="panel-body">
    Directed By : {{movie.Director}}</br>
    Release Year : {{movie.ReleaseYear}}</br>
    Language : {{movie.Language}}
</div>
```

Comment: put commonServices  getMovie function

Comment: you should call it like this to handle asynchronus call  `commonServices.getMovie().then(function(res){   $scope.movie = res   })`

Comment: you do have `movieDetailController` assigned to the page in which you print  `$scope.movie`?

Comment: Service code added. @Dev-One yes the controller and page is linked and were working prior to this function handler issue.

Comment: Where is code for commonServices.changeLocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative solution by passing the controller function to the isolated scope as below. Sharing this so that someone else get the benefit too.

Modified the directive to accept a function (not the change in template ng-click and scope)

```
movieBank.directive('movieSummary', function(){
    return{
        restrict : 'E',
        template : <input type="button" value="Detail" class="btn btn-primary button" ng-click="details({m : movie});">',
         scope : {
             details : '&'
         }
    }
});
```

passing the controller function when using the directive

```
<movie_Summary details="goToMovieDetail(movie)"></movieSummary>
```

Controller where the directive is being used

```
movieBank.controller('movieListController', function($scope, commonServices){

    $scope.goToAddMovie = function(){
        commonServices.changeLocation('/add');
    }

    $scope.goToMovieDetail = function(movie){
        commonServices.setMovie(movie);
        commonServices.changeLocation('/movieDetail');
    }
});
```